# How to access `this` inside a renderRow of a ListView?

Tags: javascript, android, listview, react-native

I'm having trouble to run a function for the onPress event inside a row of a `ListView`. I'm following the React Native tutorial trying to continue from there. It seems it's using ES6 syntax style.

This is the relevant part of the code.

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */

import React, {  
  TouchableHighlight,
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  Image,
  ListView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';

class AwesomeProject extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.something = this.something.bind(this); // <-- Trying this, not even sure why
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      }),
      loaded: false,
    };
  }

//
//Irrelevant code here. Fetching stuff and renderLoadingView
//

  something = function(){
    console.log('something');
    Alert.alert(
      'Alert Title',
      'alertMessage',
    );
  }


  render() {
    console.log('this', this); //this is an instance of AwesomeProject
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
      return this.renderLoadingView();
    }

    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderMovie}
        style={styles.listView}
        />
    );
  }

  renderMovie(movie) {
    console.log('Not this', this); //this is not an instance of AwesomeProject
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {console.log(this); this.something()}}>
     <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          source={{uri: movie.posters.thumbnail}}
          style={styles.thumbnail}                    
        />
        <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.title}

          >{movie.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.year}>{movie.year}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
       </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}

//
//More irrelevant code here. Styles and the 
//

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

I'm unable to run the `something` function. I've tried various syntax without success. The problem seems to be that `this` is not what I expect it to be, and it doesn't have the variable `something` defined.

The only way I had to make it work was to declare an external variable with `var something = function(){...}` outside the AwesomeProject class.

Is there a way to access `something` while being declared inside `AwesomeProject`? Is this maybe a bad practice according to flux architecture or something?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Turns out I found the solution myself, here: https://github.com/goatslacker/alt/issues/283#issuecomment-115391700

<strike>The problem is that with ES6 syntax you have no autobinding of `this`, so you need to do it yourself.</strike>

> I've learned a bit more since I posted this answer. The real problem is that `this` is "bound" when the function is executed, not when it's declared. It points to the object the function is attached to **when called**. For example:
>
> ```js
> obj.foo(); //inside foo, this points to obj
> bar(); //inside bar, this points to the global object (or undefined in strict mode)
> ```
>
> In my example the function `this.renderMovie()` is passed as a parameter. So inside ListView it will be a "local variable". It **will be called** "detached" from any object, like the `bar()` example before, so `this` will not be what I expect.
>
> It's possible to force the binding of `this`.

There are 3 possible solutions to my problem, and I like the 3rd one the best:

## Option 1: Manually bind this on call

On the code, replace the referece to `{this.renderMovie}` whith `{this.renderMovie.bind(this)}`

```
  render() {
    console.log('this', this); //this is an instance of AwesomeProject
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
      return this.renderLoadingView();
    }

    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderMovie.bind(this)} //<-- change here
        style={styles.listView}
        />
    );
  }
```

## Option 2: Do the binding on the constructor

And of course, bind the right function:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.something = this.something.bind(this); // <-- Not this function
    this.renderMovie = this.renderMovie.bind(this); // <-- This function!!
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      }),
      loaded: false,
    };
  }
```

## Option 3: use the arrow syntax and let them do the job

I like this one the best. You just need to declare the involved function using the arrow syntax so this:

```
  renderMovie(movie) {
    //code here
  }
```

becomes this:

```
  renderMovie = (movie) => {
    //code here
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to https://stackoverflow.com/a/36779517/6100821

### Option 4: use bind operator

```
<ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={::this.renderMovie} //<-- cleaner, than bind
    style={styles.listView}
    />
```

Be careful, it's just a [proposal](https://github.com/zenparsing/es-function-bind), not a standard!